# Medieval: Total War won't work on any computer I've tried... help?

Tags: technical-issues, medieval-total-war

Medieval: Total War won't work on any computer I've tried.

So, I've tried this game on many, many computers, including my main Windows 8.1, A Windows XP, Vista, 98... 2000, too.

In my main Windows 8.1, it shows the splash: "Medieval: Total War", and then it goes, staying in Task Manager, but not showing any game.

In the XP, (all the other computers were Virtual Machines, run in Virtual Box) it installed properly, as it did in all the other computers, but it would always have problems initialising DirectX. It would say things in the error.txt document like:

```
DirectX call : ERR_INVALIDCAPS
```

or something like that. And sometimes:

```
DirectX call : ERR_NOINTERFACE
```

Any ideas...? This is quite frustrating.

Comment: In regards to the systems you ran in VirtualBox, nearly any game that uses any kind of 3d graphics will not run in a virtual environment, which is also a probable cause of the problems with initialising DirectX.

Comment: @IvoCoumans – oh, dear. Then... any ideas for the Windows 8.1!?

Comment: No clue really. A lot of people seem to have the issue, without a solution at hand.

Comment: Damn. Oh well... it was only £2.99, so... I guess I didn't waste much (it was from Oxfam.)

Comment: Have you tried using compatibility mode? Right click on the executable for the program, property, compatibility, select Windows XP from the menu

Comment: Of course. First thing I tried. Nothing...

Comment: @wolfboyft Also, it seems that [the game is on Steam now](http://store.steampowered.com/app/345260/). Have you tried redeeming the product code?

Comment: @PrivatePansy Well... I did buy it second hand from Oxfam... worth a shot though. Maybe it was never used!! :P So, where is this code in the box? Or do you not know...

Comment: did you try "run as admin"?

Comment: Possibly related, I had similar problems with Rome.  I believe 32-bit XP was the only configuration I managed to get it running on.  Is your XP 64-bit?

Answer (score 1):

**First** of. Trying to run the game in VBox will most likely fail if it is DX based.

**Secondly**, Make sure you installed the DirectX that is on the disk.(could be 7 or 9, IDK). [Another note, DX 8 (if I remember correctly) was very, very buggy and gave a lot of problems]

**Third:** Try running the game in compatibility mode. Normally this is a long shot and it wont work. :(

**Fourth:** You could try to reclaim it on steam (or buy a new copy if possible) , but there is a good chance that it might still give you a bunch of issues. There is a lot of people that bought the steam version with CTD(crash to desktop) problems.

**Fifth:** Trying to run the game in Windows 8.1 will probably not work, even with a lot of tweaking etc. Put your time into getting it to run on XP instead. I believe there is a site that provides old copies of DX, but I will not link it because I don't know the site or used it. (Google will help). Just remember that the earlier versions is not as cross compatible as DX9,10 and 11. *If possible, install the DX that is on the disk!*

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense that it at least installed on XP, considering the game came out in 2002.

On 8.1, you can try to reinstall the game in compatibility mode, but I think you're out of luck. If you have a Win7 install, you can try one of the solutions [on this page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/CompatCenter/ProductDetailsViewer?Type=Software&Name=Medieval%3A%20Total%20War&ModelOrVersion=&Vendor=Sega&Locale=&LastSearchTerm=&BreadcrumbPath=&TempOsid=Windows%207). It's unlikely that you're going to have a ton success just due to the age of the game and the changes in hardware and software in the past decade.

Comment: It never worked on XP...?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your post

Comment: That's okay, don't worry.